# How to replace field in the input array with json label's value?

Tags: javascript

I have a json variable which contains label and respective values.
Label is my category name and value is my category id.

```
var src = {
"categories": [{
    "label": "travel",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "label": "food",
    "value": "2"
}, {
    "label": "banking",
    "value": "3"
}, {
    "label": "movies",
    "value": "4"
}
]};
```

I would like to have a function which replaces name field in my input array with the value as per the above json source.

Here is my input:

```
data=[
{'id': 0, 'name': 'banking', 'catvalue': 18}, 
{'id': 1, 'name': 'travel', 'catvalue': 12}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': 'movies', 'catvalue': 33}, 
{'id': 3, 'name': 'food', 'catvalue': 45}
];
```

After the modification, output should be returned as

```
[
{'id': 0, 'name': '3', 'catvalue': 18}, 
{'id': 1, 'name': '1', 'catvalue': 12}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': '4', 'catvalue': 33}, 
{'id': 3, 'name': '2', 'catvalue': 45}
]
```

Please note that name value is replaced with the value that is available in the json as per the label (name). [label in json==name in input array]

I tried using replace function, but facing difficulty implementing it in the loop.

Could you share any approach for achieving this requirement ?

Here is what I tried-

```
var d1 = [];

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  var nm = data[key].name;
  if (nm == src.Categories.label) {
    data[name] = src.Categories.value;
  }
  d1.push(data[key]);

});
```

what am I missing?

Also tried using replace function to replace name in array with the label value of json source variable. But couldn't figure out what is missing.

Comment: Did you try anything? SO is not intended to write you code for you.

Comment: True.. I tried something.. let me update it

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? Approach is also fine with me, I can try myself

Comment: Will the elements in src always be in order? I.e, will the first one always be 1, then 2, etc? Or can they be mixed up in different order?

Comment: it can be in random as well.

Comment: forEach() doesn't give you the key it gives you the current item and the index number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: do you want to edit the `data` array in place or should the result be a new different array?

Comment: either of it is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the corresponding source value based on the data name:

```
data.forEach(function(el) {
  var match = src.categories.filter(function(obj) {return obj.label === el.name;}),
      value = match[0] && match[0].value;

  el.name = value || 'NOT_FOUND';
});
```

#### See example:

```js
var src = {
  "categories": [{
    "label": "travel",
    "value": "1"
  }, {
    "label": "food",
    "value": "2"
  }, {
    "label": "banking",
    "value": "3"
  }, {
    "label": "movies",
    "value": "4"
  }]
};
var data = [{
  'id': 0,
  'name': 'banking',
  'catvalue': 18
}, {
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'travel',
  'catvalue': 12
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'movies',
  'catvalue': 33
}, {
  'id': 3,
  'name': 'food',
  'catvalue': 45
}, {
  'id': 4,
  'name': 'notInArray',
  'catvalue': 48
}];

data.forEach(function(el) {
  var match = src.categories.filter(function(obj) {return obj.label === el.name;}),
      value = match[0] && match[0].value;
  
  el.name = value || 'NOT_FOUND';
});

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh, am checking this

Comment: Hi Josh, how can I use if else condition in filter.. just in case if match is not found?

Comment: @SathishPanduga Updated. See the example.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop to go through each item in your `data` array, for each one call a function that return the corresponding value for the given label.

```
var src = {
"categories": [{
    "label": "travel",
    "value": "1"
}, {
    "label": "food",
    "value": "2"
}, {
    "label": "banking",
    "value": "3"
}, {
    "label": "movies",
    "value": "4"
}
]};

var data=[
{'id': 0, 'name': 'banking', 'catvalue': 18}, 
{'id': 1, 'name': 'travel', 'catvalue': 12}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': 'movies', 'catvalue': 33}, 
{'id': 3, 'name': 'food', 'catvalue': 45}
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var current = data[i];
    var label = current.name;
    var value = getValueForLabel(label);
    current.name = value;
}

console.log(data);

function getValueForLabel(label) {
    for (var i = 0; i < src.categories.length; i++) {
        var current = src.categories[i];
        if (current.label === label) {
            return current.value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Really though it would be better if you changed the structure of your data such that it was a map and not an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it

Comment: No problem. I encourage you to try both this iterative solution and the other two functional programming answers. Its worth knowing how to apply both techniques.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.forEach(function(o) {
  var match = src.categories.find(function(category) { return category.label === o.name; });
  if (match) {
    o.name = match.value;
  } else {
    // Error handling
  }
});
```

Depending on how many lookups you are planning to do, and how large you expect categories to become, you may benefit from generating a lookup table that maps from names to values (i.e. `{ "travel": "1", ... }`. This would allow constant time lookups rather than linear time lookups every time you perform this operation.